# Proving limit of an iterative sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let

$a_1=\sqrt{2}$, and $a_2=\sqrt{a_1+2}$, $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n+2}$ I need to show that the limit of this sequence is 2, but I can I do this, I can not use epsilon criterion here, since it is iterative. I have already shown that this sequence is bounded by 2 with induction, but I also need to prove that the exact limit 2.

edit: thank you everyone for the answers! such great approaches that I am having a difficulty to chose the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can readily see that, if the limit exists, it must be 2. Assume that the limit is $L$. Then, since $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n+2}$, and thus $\lim a_{n+1} = \lim a_n =L$, we must have that $L = \sqrt{L+2}$. From here you conclude that $L=2$. Regarding the existence of limit,

1. $a_n \ge \sqrt{2}$ and $a_n <2$ (the sequence is bounded)
2. $
   a_{n+1}-a_n =\sqrt{a_n+2}-a_n = \frac{(a_n+1)(2-a_n)}{\sqrt{a_n+2}+a_n}>0
   $ (the sequence is monotonous)

and, therefore, the sequence in convergent.

Answer (score 6):

The sequence is monotonically increasing between 1 and 2, so it has a limit. At the limit, $$l = \sqrt{l +2},$$ so solving the quadratic you get $l=2.$

Comment: great, thank you

Answer (score 2):

$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n+2}$$
$$2=\sqrt{2+2}$$
so

$$|a_{n+1}-2|=|\frac{a_n-2}{\sqrt{a_n+2}+2}|$$

$$\le \frac{|a_n-2|}{2}$$

$$\cdots$$
$$\le \frac{|a_1-2|}{2^n}$$
$$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n=2$$

Answer (score 1):

First observe that $a_n>0$ for all $n$. Now prove that the sequence is strictly increasing, we have$$\begin{align*}a_{n+1}>a_n & \iff \sqrt{a_n+2}>a_n \\
& \underset{a_n>0\forall n}{\iff}a_n+2>a_n^2 \\
& \iff a_n^2-a_n-2<0
\end{align*}$$but the latter is true since the function $f(x)=x^2-x-2$ is negative on $(0,2)$ because its principal coefficient is positive and has roots $x_1=-1$ and $x_2=2$. Therefore, the sequence is increasing. 
Since it is increasing and bounded, it has a limit $\ell$, which is nonnegative because every term in the sequence is. Now$$\ell =\lim \limits _{n\to \infty}a_n=\lim \limits _{n\to \infty}a_{n+1}=\lim \limits _{n\to \infty}\sqrt{a_n+2}=\sqrt{\ell +2}$$hence $\ell =\sqrt{\ell +2}$, so $\ell ^2=\ell +2$, this quadratic has roots $-1$ and $2$, since $\ell \geq 0$, we get $\ell =2$, as we wanted.

Comment: awesome, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way,

$$\begin{align}\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots}}}}_{ n ~ \text{terms},~n≥1}=2\cos \frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\end{align}$$

Comment: i find this approach really interesting, could you explain how you derive this expression?