# Nonlinear recurrence relation with square root

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have been asked about solving (EDIT: find explicit $a_n$) the recurrence relation containing square root, but I have tried days without success.

\begin{align}
a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n},
\end{align}
with $a_1=\sqrt 2$.
I tried to use the ODE equivalence for the homogeneous equation $L=(u')^2-u=0$ like this
\begin{align}
L'=u'(2u''-1)=0,
\end{align}
so $u=n^2/4+c_1n+c_2$ where $c_1$, $c_2$ are constants. Nothing can be obtained further...

Will it be the characteristic equation $x^2-x-2=(x+1)(x-2)=0$? Then $a_n$ would be related to $2^n$?

What techniques or strategies can be used to solve them?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4117644.

Comment: By "solve" do you mean a closed formula for $a_n$?  Or just information about the limit?

Comment: I was trying to find the closed expression.

Comment: @Martin R: Thanks for the link! Can this $\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots}}}}_{ n ~ \text{terms},~n≥1}=2\cos \frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}$ be derived?

Comment: @MathArt: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053715. – All these (and more) related questions can be found with a search on https://approach0.xyz/.